# WiFi Adapter Internet Connection Drop

Tags: wireless-networking

**Symptoms**

Internet connection is mostly stable, but will occasionally drop in situations where there is high throughput on the connection, such as downloading large files or streaming video (sometimes it will be stable for hours, other times it might drop a couple times per hour). When this happens, attempting to access the router times out. This usually lasts for up to a minute. As soon as the connection to the router is reestablished the internet access works again without issue.

**System**

- ROG Strix Z370-E Gaming
- onboard Realtek 8822BE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC
- 5 GHz channel WiFi connection
- Windows 10 (Version 10.0.17134 Build 17134)
- Google Fiber router GFRG200

**Troubleshooting**

I've had this problem for over a year at this point. It started on my previous PC build based on P8Z77-V with A7000 WiFi USB Adapter when I had to switch from an ethernet connection to wifi. The new system has this problem with both the onboard wifi adapter and with A7000. No issues when connected to the router via ethernet. Tested also with two different laptops (Windows 7 and a macbook) and smartphone and the issue does not reproduce there. I've tried several different drivers for both adapters, the latest today with 2024.0.4.102 driver for the onboard adapter.

The router is within 10 feet of the PC with no obstructions in between. Looking for interference with Wi-Fi analyzer doesn't indicate much congestion on the 5GHz frequency. I've also tried changing the channels with no effect.

I recorded a session of this happening while streaming from Twitch with Wireshark and nothing really stands out in the recording other than a number of TCP Dup ACKs before the connection is lost.

What would be some further steps to take to narrow down the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the router may not be up to the job.... and, the fact that you mention wifi analysis makes me think you are quite technical.

If this was me and I was in your circumstance, I would attempt to set up any sort of remote monitoring to the router - or at the least, ssh/telnet and run `w` or similar... but, hopefully it does have some sort of SNMP agent.

Then, I would just wait and monitor.

My guess is that your router is either defective or simply not up to the job - possibly under high CPU (or routing) utilisation, the Wifi chip is not functioning as it should.

I would also attempt to disable wireless, setup a standard access point (or use another router through the lan port, disable DHCP, assign a lan IP), and see if you can use it fine with that.

All in all though, as someone who has worked with an ISP and seen this sort of thing day in and day out, I really think the router is either defective, using the wrong power adapter, or, just isn't up to the job.