# Connection to internet lost intermitently

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wireless-router

Every so often, Windows 10 Pro 1909 on my Dell XPS 8920 would be unable to open new internet connections. It's been like this for a couple years maybe (so earlier builds of Win10 as well). It usually resumes operation on its own without taking a reboot.

Yesterday I noticed I couldn't navigate the internet while a 4GB/~7Mbps download was in progress. As the downloads goes just fine, I can't have any other use for the internet. I have a 50Mbps link. I paused the download, and internet connectitivity restore shortly after. It might be coincidence.

I opened Resource Monitor and couldn't find anything suspicious, even though I'm not sure I would identify it if anything was there. I tried pinging an IP listed there but it failed. Today, the ping worked.

Tried navigating to my router's admin panel to no avail. That's really odd isn't it?

Notes:

- On HOSTS file, I had this entry: `127.0.0.1 local.somedomain.com`. `somedomain.com` could be offline every once in a while. I commented it out now.
- I don't recall it happening when connected through Ethernet, even though I use very rarely. (it happened just now, I plugged a cable, it took about 30s-1m to identify the Ethernet connection, at this point Internet came back, again, it can be coincidence. okay, internet lost over Ethernet now, I can ping the router but not google.com, internet works on phone)
- I could use my phone to browse the internet during that time.

PS: This question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1401476/wifi-adapter-internet-connection-drop) is close to what I'm facing, even though here it's not just wifi, Ethernet too.

**UPDATE**

I thought I'd add another couple issues on other devices, which might be related.

1. Chromecast older design (have it for about 6/7 years) about 10 meters away through one wall, usually works well until loses internet and is unable to reconnect to wifi. Rebooting router usually brings Chromecast back. I've read it could be a Chromecast issue.
2. Moto Z Play also loses wireless connection. I've read this is somewhat common issue. Never managed to fix, even though it was working fine for many weeks. Issue returned a couple weeks ago.

Also, I don't know how to manually update router's firmware, but I think ISP sends updates regularly. About a month ago, I setup Dynamic DNS (noip.com) on the router, but disable to see if it would help with connectitivity issues. Wireless card still gets a static IP from router.

Comment: And with which version did it first manifest, since you said in your first graf it's been misbehaving for a couple of years?

Comment: Two years is a long time to allow a problem like this to fester. Try running TCP/IP Reset:  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
Then: ipconfig /flushdns
Then: restart the computer   ... Then update your wireless NIC driver to the newest version

Comment: I'm thinking in resetting my router to factory settings. It's a mitrastar provided by ISP.

Comment: Yes, this sounds like a crappy router, probably with connection tracking issues. Can you replace the router with something decent?

Comment: @John problem came back. Plugged a wire and Internet came in a couple seconds. Earlier I lost connectitivity even on wire. Odd.

Comment: @davidgo I can add another router to my setup (TP Link, about 3/ years old). I was using it before but removed since I got my PC closer to the router and router is wireless as well.

Comment: I'd try that. I suspect it will fix the problem - but if not you have another data point.

Comment: Also dynamic DNS is not the cause of your pain.

Comment: Ask the ISP for a new router. At a minimum, that eliminates a point of failure

Comment: As another troubleshooting step, I reset the router to factory. So far so good. So @davidgo & John are right, I need to replace it. If either of you would like to post as an answer I'll accept. Just wonder how I got stuck with that issue for 2 years :(